# Mongoimport json data and then big data

Tags: python, json, mongodb, mongoimport, bigdata

I'm stuck in doing a very simple import operation in MongoDB. I have a file, 200MB in size, JSON format. Its a feeds dump, format as: `{"some-headers":"", "dump":[{"item-id":"item-1"},{"item-id":"item-2"},...]}`
This json feed contains words in languages other than english too, like Chinese, Japanese, Characters, etc.
I tried to do a mongoimport as `mongoimport --db testdb --collection testcollection --file dump.json` but possibly, because the data is a bit complex, its treating `dump` as a column, resulting in error, due to 4MB column value limit.
I further tried and a python script:

```
import simplejson
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.Connection("localhost",27017)
db = conn.testdb
c = db.testcollection
o = open("dump.json")
s = simplejson.load(o)
for x in s['dump']:
     c.insert(x)
o.close()
```

Python is killed while running this thing, possibly due to the very limited resources I'm trying to work with.
I reduced the filesize, by getting a new json dump at 50MB, now due to ASCII issues, python is troubling me again. 
I am looking for options both way using `mongoimport` and with above python script. Any further solutions shall also be greatly appreciated.

Also, I might some day reach the json dump ~GBs, so if there will be some other solution I should consider then, pl do highlight.

Comment: Can you manipulate the json file so its just the dump array?  Then do a mongoimport?  Otherwise its trying to load all the data into a single document and hitting the max document size limit.